# ReactJS- Build the html with embedded response of services/API

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, server-side-rendering

In a React app, when running "npm build," I want to include all the embedded responses from various services/APIs in the resulting HTML. This way, the build files can be used as static HTML files. Has anyone dealt with this kind of problem before?

Comment: just so I understand, when you run npm build you want to make a request to an API and save the response to the dist folder

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will suit your needs, NextJS provides this functionality out of box by using getStaticProps,

During build, getStaticProps can be used to make an API call, and this will used to generate the HTML page, thus no API call will be made when site is loaded. The API calls would already have prepopulated the values during build.

If this suits your needs, you can refer [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-static-props)